# error C3646: 'closure' : unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, overriding, specifier

**I got the following error:**

```
error C3646: 'closure' : unknown override specifier
```

**The code:**

```
void BaseOperator::mousebutton_cb(EventObject* sender, EventArgs* calldata, void* closure)
{
    xd3D::Operation::Operator::BaseOperator* operator = (xd3D::Operation::Operator::BaseOperator*)closure;
    MouseButtonEventArgs* e = (MouseButtonEventArgs*)calldata;
    if (e->Status == Down)
        operator->OnMouseButtonDown(e);
    else
        operator->OnMouseButtonUp(e);
}
```

Do you know why I have this error?

Comment: Johannes' explanation is right. I think that's an interesting mistake to make, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`operator` is a keyword. The sequence `operator =` tries to declare an assignment operator which in your case would have a pointer parameter type. And your compiler wants to parse the very last `closure` as a special specifier like `override` (afaik an extension of MSVC), `const` or such.

Rename the variable to something else, like `myoperator`.

Comment: I notice that SO has helpfully shown the `operator` keyword in a dark blue colour, instead of the usual black.